# Bluetooth LE Cadence and Speed Sensor not sending notifications on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm having an issue with a Bluetooth LE Cadence and Speed sensor (Wahoo SC). I'm using the Android BluetoothGattLe sample app, which I have adapted for the Cadence and Speed Sensor.

It works fine with the heartrate monitor. The relevant code is below. With the heartrate monitor onCharacteristicChanged fires every second, as heartrate changes. However, when I connect the Cadence and Speed sensor, nothing happens. This callback doesn't seem to get triggered - although I know that onConnectionStateChange gets triggered on connection.

Any thoughts?

```
    /**
 * Service for managing connection and data communication with a GATT server hosted on a
 * given Bluetooth LE device.
 */
public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {
    private final static String TAG = BluetoothLeService.class.getSimpleName();

    private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private String mBluetoothDeviceAddress;
    private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
    private int mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;

    private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 1;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 2;

    public final static String ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED";
    public final static String ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED";
    public final static String ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED";
    public final static String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
    public final static String EXTRA_DATA =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA";

    public final static UUID UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT =
            UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT);
    public final static UUID UUID_CSC_MEASUREMENT =
            UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CSC_MEASUREMENT);

    // Implements callback methods for GATT events that the app cares about.  For example,
    // connection change and services discovered.
    private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            String intentAction;
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
                // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
                Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                        mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                         BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                         int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you set notify or indicate to true if yes then check whether  setCharacteristicNotification() return value. and check whether you have permission to read characteristic. and also please print the status value of onDescripterWrite Callback method.

```
  for notification
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#notification

descriptor call back method javadoc

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onDescriptorWrite%28android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor,%20int%29
```